# Adobe Flash for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium, lts, adobe

I know there are a lot of questions about this, I have tried many of them. I still cannot utilize Adobe on my Chromium. I have updated and reinstalled and still nothing. I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux and would appreciate any help on the subject. Please no more links to similar questions since they seem to be more specific to other issues than the one I am having. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also started trying Pepper Flash though I think this is specific to FireFox and if so would like to know how to completely remove this program safely.

Comment: pepper flash after the update did it,.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pepper Flash is Chrome/Chromium only (made by Google), not Firefox. If you want to uninstall it, you can do

`sudo apt-get remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

but really, there is no reason to as it can coexist with the Adobe version of Flash.

To install flash, do

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`

If that doesn't work, we will need more details as far as what exactly is going wrong.

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer

Comment: I used many different lines to get adobe onto my computer however it still says I need to update to version 10 or greater to use Pandora for instance. Or when trying to stream a video its says "This plug-in is not supported" or "an error has occurred-please try again later"

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't read your question careful enough... You say you're on 12.04 LTS... why? I believe the reason you're getting those errors is the version of flash in the repositories for that version of Ubuntu is way outdated... 12.04 is **old**. If you don't have a good reason to be on 12.04, update to 14.04!

Comment: I am updating now. The reason I am still operating on 12.04LTS is the last time I tried to update all I got was a black screen after Ubuntu flashed on the screen and had to reboot through Gnu terminal to get my computer back... being that deep scares me.

Comment: OK so I updated and still the same errors. I reinstalled Adobe 11 plugin through Ubuntu Application Store and still when I go to Pandora it says I need to download the latest version of Adobe...

Comment: when I entered that line to install flash it gave me a few options to pick Specifically from. [@Termhn]

Answer (score -1):

Adobe has a tiny remark on their site:

Note: Ubuntu Linux requires libhal (Hardware Abstraction Layer). Install hal to play the protected content.

This brought me to http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10. 
By following the instructions at the bottom of the page I installed libhal and my Flash problems with Chrome in Ubuntu14.10 are over.

-edit- Disregard, after a while Flash crashed again....., sorry.